GoPro Dashboard Overlay - Total Distance
Is there an easy way to get James Richardson's GoPro Dashboard Overlay tool to display total distance or average speed? I'm not figuring it out. The default render shown in the docs doesn't seem to show how to display a Total Distance widget.
My first render was this:
venv/bin/gopro-dashboard.py GX010027.MP4 test.MP4

and that generated a render that looked something like this:

I can probably figure out how to get rid of the temp, RPM and BPM gauges since I don't have data for them by using Jack Henschel's XML layout file posted here, but I don't see anywhere in the documentation on how to use a command line parameter or modify the XML config file so I can get a Total Distance widget.
Is there some way I can pass a command line parameter to gopro-dashboard.py or modify the XML Layout file to get a Total Distance widget?
NOTE:

Units of distance for Richardson's tool are mentioned here, but I see no mention of a Total Distance widget
A demo of Richardson's tool can be found on YouTube under the title GoPro Overlay Promo 2024 01


The instructions manual mentions a "Distance" gauge that's "limited" to a long list of models. It also mention an "Add Gauge" entry in the Bottom area - do you have this?

@harrymc - I'm not familiar with the GoPro Telemetry Extractor. It's probably out of budget for me. I was asking specifically about James Richardson's GoPro Dashboard Overlay project mentioned in the links above.

I think the solution is to use an odometer widget but I haven't tested it yet:
https://github.com/time4tea/gopro-dashboard-overlay/blob/main/gopro_overlay/layouts/example.xml

I wound up using the Odometer widget shown in this example.
My XML file was essentially default layout with this line added
<component type="metric" x="900" y="600"
metric="speed" units="mph" format=".1f" size="32"/>

I copied that code verbatim from two of Richardson's examples once I figured out the problem was that I needed to use an Odometer widget.
My render command wound up being
venv/bin/gopro-dashboard.py --generate overlay \
   --profile overlay --layout-xml layout.xml \
   GX020027.MP4 test200.mov

The important part of the render command above is the
--layout-xml layout.xml

switch. I got this information from the Henschel and Richardson references cited above. My current XML file still needs some work to correct the size and labeling of the odometer widget, but it is working and is listed below:
<layout>
    <composite x="260" y="30" name="date_and_time">
        <component type="datetime" x="0" y="0" format="%Y/%m/%d" size="16" align="right"/>
        <component type="datetime" x="0" y="24" format="%H:%M:%S.%f" truncate="5" size="32" align="right"/>
    </composite>

    <composite x="1644" y="0" name="gps_info">
        <frame name="gps-lock" x="226" y="24" width="32" height="32" bg="0,0,0,128" cr="5" opacity="0.4">
            <component type="gps-lock-icon" size="32"/>
         </frame>

        <composite y="36">
            <component type="text" x="0" y="0" size="16" align="left">GPS INFO</component>
            <component type="text" x="0" y="24" size="16" align="left">Lat: </component>
            <component type="text" x="128" y="24" size="16" align="left">Lon: </component>
            <component type="metric" x="118" y="24" metric="lat" dp="6" size="16" align="right" cache="False"/>
            <component type="metric" x="256"    y="24" metric="lon" dp="6" size="16" align="right" cache="False"/>
        </composite>
    </composite>

    <composite x="16" y="800" name="big_mph">
        <component type="metric_unit" metric="speed" units="speed" size="16">{:~c}</component>
        <component type="metric" x="0" y="0" metric="speed" units="speed" dp="0" size="160" />
    </composite>

    <component type="chart" name="gradient_chart" x="400" y="980"/>

    <composite x="220" y="980" name="gradient">
        <component type="text" x="70" y="0" size="16">SLOPE(%)</component>
        <component type="icon" x="0" y="0" file="slope-triangle.png" size="64"/>
        <component type="metric" x="70" y="18" metric="gradient" dp="0" size="32" />
    </composite>

    <composite x="16" y="980" name="altitude">
        <component type="metric_unit" x="70" y="0" metric="alt" units="alt" size="16">ALT({:~C})</component>
        <component type="icon" x="0" y="0" file="mountain.png" size="64"/>
        <component type="metric" x="70" y="18" metric="alt" units="alt" dp="0" size="32" />
    </composite>

    <component type="metric" x="850" y="750" metric="odo" units="miles" dp="2" size="32" rgb="255,255,0"/>

    <component type="moving_map" name="moving_map" x="1644" y="100" size="256" zoom="16" corner_radius="35"/>
    <component type="journey_map" name="journey_map" x="1644" y="376" size="256" corner_radius="35"/>
</layout>

It's heavily based on the work from Henschel and Richardson.

